# Docker-compose: Problem with ports in docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying run my App by docker-compose but I have problem with my ports.
When I use command docker-compose --build the application runs on port 5000, although I have a completely different port established ,so only the Login view is displayed strong text

Terminal:

FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.

`components["port"] = int(components["port"])`

When you try login:

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
        container_name: app
        ports:
            - "5005:5005"
        entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
            - POSTGER_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
            - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
            - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
            - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
        hostname: subscription-app
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
    db:
        restart: always
        image: postgres:14.3-alpine3.16
        container_name: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_PORT_INTERNAL=${POSTGRES_PORT_INTERNAL}
        ports:
            - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT_INTERNAL}"
        hostname: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
            interval: 5s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 6
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY .requirements/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY app .
ENV FLASK_APP=.
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
RUN chmod u+x entrypoint.sh
CMD [ "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
flask run --host="${HOST}"
```

Comment: does the `${HOST}` resolve inside the app container?

Comment: Yes it resolves , I also tried to use POSTGRES_HOST but there was the same result

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be using `flask run` in prod dockerfile, but deploy with proper server (like gunicorn or uwsgi) instead. It is well documented in [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/). Unless explicitly told otherwise, flask runs on port 5000, but you map 5005:5005 (5005 of container should be free, and host 5005 consequently does not serve flask). It is unclear where is `HOST` envvar defined (I see only POSTGRES_HOST). It is hard to answer this question in current form, I can only propose `ports: 5005:5000` in compose file, but HOST is odd anyway.